# Python - Split strings into words within a list of lists

Tags: python, list, split, python-2.x

I have the following list of lists ():

```
[[u' why not giving me service'], [u' option to'], [u' removing an'], [u' verify name and '], [u' my credit card'], [u' credit card'], [u' theres something on my visa']]
```

and I have the following questions:
First, what are these `u'` appearing in front of every of my sublists?
Second, how can I plit my sublists into separate words, i.e. have something like this:

```
 [[why, not, giving, me, service], [option, to], [removing, an], [verify, name, and], [my, credit, card], [credit, card], [theres, something, on, my, visa]]
```

I already tried the `split` function, but I get the following error message: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`
Thanx a lot.

Comment: `u'` indicates that the string is unicode. Lists don't have split method. Strings do.

Comment: look up flatten list of lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
list_1 = [[u' why not giving me service'], [u' option to'], [u' removing an'], [u' verify name and '], [u' my credit card'], [u' credit card'], [u' theres something on my visa']]
res = []
for list in list_1:
    res.append(str(list[0]).split())

print res
```

Output:

```
[['why', 'not', 'giving', 'me', 'service'], ['option', 'to'], ['removing', 'an'], ['verify', 'name', 'and'], ['my', 'credit', 'card'], ['credit', 'card'], ['theres', 'something', 'on', 'my', 'visa']]
```

**u'** represents unicode, I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 2):

With `str.split()` function:

```
l = [[u' why not giving me service'], [u' option to'], [u' removing an'], [u' verify name and '], [u' my credit card'], [u' credit card'], [u' theres something on my visa']]

result = [_[0].split() for _ in l]
print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['why', 'not', 'giving', 'me', 'service'], ['option', 'to'], ['removing', 'an'], ['verify', 'name', 'and'], ['my', 'credit', 'card'], ['credit', 'card'], ['theres', 'something', 'on', 'my', 'visa']]
```

Comment: Why use an underscore tho?

Comment: Well, yes, upvoters, this is extremely simple, but it doesn't consider, for example `[[u'a b c', u'd e f'], [..]]` -> multiple strings in an inner list.

Comment: Funnily enough, I was wondering why using the underscore... Can you explain why not give it a proper name?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, what are the pitfalls of using `_` in this context?

Comment: No pitfalls per se, but conventionally you'll use those for throw-away objects.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, something like that ... just throwing away

Comment: Meh, no need to be pedantic, however, I don't see how are you throwing it away when you're later using it in `_[0].split()`.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye, fell free to share a related grounded link from PEP8 for this concrete case. I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[[u' why not giving me service'], [u' option to'], [u' removing an'], [u' verify name and '], [u' my credit card'], [u' credit card'], [u' theres something on my visa']]
[[y.split() for y in m] for m in x]
```

here's the output of it:

```
In [3]: [[y.split() for y in m] for m in x]
Out[3]: 
[[[u'why', u'not', u'giving', u'me', u'service']],
 [[u'option', u'to']],
 [[u'removing', u'an']],
 [[u'verify', u'name', u'and']],
 [[u'my', u'credit', u'card']],
 [[u'credit', u'card']],
 [[u'theres', u'something', u'on', u'my', u'visa']]]
```